# Why can't i use a while loop for writing something in a txt file

Tags: python

I have this simple while loop:

```
f = open('test.txt','a')

i = 0
while i <= 5:

    f.write('test')

i = i + 1

f.close()
```

Every time i execute this code my python crashes. Is there a reason why that occurs?

Comment: You have an infinite loop. You need to indent the `i = i + 1` line so that it's inside the loop.

Comment: Furthermore, your `test.txt` file becomes huge!

Comment: thank you, i have missed the tab there :) why does the file become that huge instead of just writing 5 times test?

Comment: @python_beginner: The loop iterates over and over again. In each iteration ``test`` is written to the file infinitely.

Comment: In your code `i` stays at zero. Forever...

Comment: i fixed it. Embarrassing mistake, but ty all

Comment: Hopefully, you'll remember next time. :) FWIW, it's a good idea to test stuff like this by printing to the console and then when that's working properly modify the code to write to disk. That way you avoid writing vast amounts of garbage to your hard drive.

Comment: You missed a tab? Please don't use tabs, use spaces instead (see [Tabs or Spaces](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#tabs-or-spaces)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are incrementing the `i` variable outside of the loop. This code is never reached, since your loop never exits. It is an infinite loop. Place `i = i + 1` within the loop:

```
f = open('test.txt','a')

i = 0
while i <= 5:

    f.write('test')    
    i = i + 1

f.close()
```

Now `i` will be increased in each iteration, while `i <= 5` holds. When `i` becomes 6, the loop exits and the file is closed.